# Implementing big data into Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js, graph-visualization, cytoscape, cytoscape-web, bigdata

I am new to Cytoscape and need some advice. I have a file that has two columns named: source & destination (edge -> end node)

For example, a sample starting from the top may look like this:

```
   src      |    dst
12.251.512  | 12.623.743
51.734.312  | 23.233.991
6334.6231.123  | 42.532.54453
```

It has roughly a million+ lines, and I need a way to visualize it.

Is Cytoscape the right tool for this kind of visualization job? If so,

What methods can be used to simplify such large networks so that visualization actually gives us some information? Any plugin/tool/technique advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have so many elements, your users are going to have trouble making sense of the graph.  Try hiding elements using the style: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/visibility

You can show N elements at a time based on filters.  What metrics you use depends on your data.  A basic one might be degree.

You could control the filtering with sliders, toggles, etc.